# Count the number of atoms in a cluster

Tags: machine-learning, image-processing, image-segmentation, data-processing

I'm trying to make a network that identifies missing atoms from an image, and is then able to count them.

So far, I have created a CNN that is able to output an image like below that solely highlights such atoms [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IDX4I.png), and I have found an OpenCV library tat I think would be able to count all the individual white spots (https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/white-and-black-dot-detection-using-opencv-python/).

However I would like to be able to count the missing atoms for a given structre: eg I've circled in red the clusters of dots that I would like my network to identify and count as a structure with 8 atoms for example. I have thought the easiest method might be to:

- Apply bounding boxes based on segmentation, crop the image and count the atoms per box,which would provide a labelled image, however a big issue would be the inclusion of additional, non-connected atoms in the box

If this approach was taken, how would I be able to create more specific-shaped boxes? I could try coloring each circle based on the area, and ignoring the other color when cropped to the bounding box size?

Personally I think the question I'm struggling with is how do I segment this image and process each cluster, or is there a smoother technique that I could use or integrate into my ML model?

[image]

Comment: Look for connected components. For each connected component, count how many pixels are in it, and divide the number by the average number of pixels per atom; the result will be the estimate of the number of atoms in the cluster.

Comment: A more general comment: Try to stick to classic image processing approaches for this problem, as suggested by the other comments. Do not try to cram this into your deep learning model.